# Excel AverageIF: Average first X cells of a given type

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of unit information for an apartment complex, including unit types, rents, and move in dates. I am trying to figure out how to calculate the average rent of the most recent 25% move-ins for each unit type (ie. 120 total 1x1's, so trying to figure out the average of the most recent 30 leases). I am trying to come up with a variable formula that can be applied to all the different unit types.

```
Unit    Type    Actual  Move In
268    1x1cr    1049    4/13/2019
171    1x1cr    1019    4/12/2019
251    1x1cr    1049    3/23/2019
292    2x2clr   1235    3/22/2019
107    1x1cr    1019    3/15/2019
225    2x2clr   1210    3/15/2019
262    1x1cr    1019    3/14/2019
224    2x2clr   1235    3/10/2019
392    2x2clr   1335    3/1/2019
271    1x1cr    1069    2/23/2019
182    1x1cr    1019    2/22/2019
155    1x1cr    1019    2/21/2019
226    2x2clr   1315    2/14/2019
385    2x2clr   1215    2/11/2019
116    1x1cr    1019    2/9/2019
189    2x2clr   1365    2/6/2019
148    1x1cr    1019    2/1/2019
150    1x1cr    1019    2/1/2019
176    1x1cr    1019    1/31/2019
130    2x2clr   1215    1/29/2019
```

For the above example the result would be:

- 1x1cr = $1,039   (first 3 of 12 1x1's averages $1,039)
- 2x2clr = $1,222.50   (first 2 of 8 2x2's averages $1,222.50)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here my attempt:

[image]

The formula in `G2`:

```
{=AVERAGEIFS($C$2:$C$21,$B$2:$B$21,F2,$D$2:$D$21,">="&LARGE(IF($B$2:$B$21=F2,$D$2:$D$21),ROUND(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$21,F2)*0.25,0)))}
```

Note it's an array formula entered through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Steps:

1) First we need to know the amount of move in's that make up 25% of the total of that type through: `=ROUND(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$21,F2)*0.25,0)`

2) Next we need to know what that nth largest value is through: `{=LARGE(IF($B$2:$B$21=F2,$D$2:$D$21),ROUND(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$21,F2)*0.25,0))}`

3) Now we have our mark and can get all values that are `>=` than this mark through our combined `AVERAGEIFS()` formula.

Note that in this case (with all different dates) it will work fine, but there might be an issue when dates of the nth largest can be the same, as the `>=` will catch multiple hits in it's calculation. Hope that makes sense :S

In that case you should try:

```
{=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$21=F2)*(ROW($B$2:$B$21)<=SMALL(IF($B$2:$B$21=F2,ROW($B$2:$B$21)-MIN(ROW($B$2:$B$21))+2),ROUND(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$21,F2)*0.25,0)))*($C$2:$C$21))/ROUND(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$21,F2)*0.25,0)}
```

Comment: Fantastic, there are several instances on the larger table where the same date issue comes into play. The alternative that you provided worked with a +3 rather than a +2. I am not 100% sure how that comes into play but wanted to play around with your provided formula first. I also adjusted round to roundup for my personal purposes. The final formula was: {=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$21=F2)*(ROW($B$2:$B$21)<=SMALL(IF($B$2:$B$21=F2,ROW($B$2:$B$21)-MIN(ROW($B$2:$B$21))+3),ROUNDUP(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$21,F2)*0.25,0)))*($C$2:$C$21))/ROUNDUP(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$21,F2)*0.25,0)}

Answer (score 0):

There'll be some smart cookie who can do this without a helper column but unfortunately, that smart cookie isn't me.

If the data you provided starts from cell **A1**, add the following formula to cell **E2** and fill down ...

```
=B2 & "_" & COUNTIF($B$1:B2,B2)
```

Add your Unit you want to average for in cell G2 ... `1x1cr`

Now I've added some working cells so you can see it built up ...

Cell H2 = `Percentage`

Cell H3 = `Count`

Cell H4 = `To Count`

Cell H5 = `To Row`

Cell H6 = `Average`

... now add the working formulas ...

Cell I2 = `25%`

Cell I3 = `=COUNTIF(B1:B21,G2)`

Cell I4 = `=ROUNDUP(I3*I2,0)`

Cell I5 = `=MATCH(G2 & "_" & I4,E1:E21,0)`

... here's the money formula ...

Cell I6 = `=AVERAGEIF(INDIRECT("B1:B"&I5),G2,INDIRECT("C1:C"&I5))`

... of course you can make it better yourself but that shows you my workings.

One thing to note is, if the 25% results in a non round number of cells, it rounds up, you can change that though.

[image]

I hope that helps.

Comment: Great alternative. I appreciate the contribution!